# Meaning of "three points" in the context of salary / equity

Tags: meaning-in-context, business-language, finance

> Alice: What (how much) are you guys getting?
>   Bob: Three points each.

Does "three points" mean three thousand/grand in this context? If yes then I assume it would be per month.

**update 1**: I heard this in the TV show named "Silicon Valley", in which the dudes use lots of informal/slang words/expressions.

**update 2**: They are also talking about the amount of equity they each get in their start-up company.

[Episode transcript](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=silicon-valley-2014&episode=s02e04)

Comment: Question updated. In Silicon Valley show.

Comment: "Silicon Valley show" isn't much context.  Do you mean a theatrical performance in the Silicon Valley, a TV show named "Silicon Valley", or something else?

Comment: I still think it needs more context other than "a Silicon Valley show."  For example, my school's faculty union pays extra money to salaried people for extracurricular activities they supervise, and this money is expressed in "points," where a point is a certain percentage of your salary. A "point" could really mean anything in your example without more information about the jargon.

Comment: It's a comedy TV show called Silicon Valley, and yeah it's about start-ups

Comment: Do you mean [three *commas*](https://threecommas.com/pages/about-us)?

Comment: I think you are both right. They are talking about both salary and equity, and I guess the guy is referring to amount of his equity when saying "three points each". Then I guess that means they will own three percents of the company?

Comment: @Aliweb It is very common to drop *percentage* before *point(s)* in business context. If *the guys* are employees other than Richard Hendricks or other CEOs, it should be 3.0%.

Comment: @Aliweb And, by the way, you can say "three percentage points" or "three percent", but not "three percents".

Comment: 'point' refers to percentage points, percentage usually of some financial instrument. With getting a loan you can buy 'points' meaning you pay to have the interest rate reduced, measured in percentage points. For this TV show, it probably refers to percent of shares or options of the total worth of the company.

Comment: It's 3% ownership of the company, and it's a bit of a misuse. "Points" is used when the term "percent" is ambiguous. Interest rates go up "10 points" when they move from 20% to 30%, or 10% of the whole. If they went up "10%", you could interpret that as going from 20% to 22%, or 10% of the current value.

Comment: It's also possible that they are referring to "basis points": one basis point = 0.01%. I'll admit this is unlikely since basis points are usually used to refer to changes in interest rates, and 0.03% is a very tiny fraction.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it refers to language peculiar to the production rather than standard everyday English. Better asked on a site devoted to shows.

Comment: While the question **as formulated** indeed seeks only an explanation of one scene in one television programme, which would be outside the scope of this site, it can be easily reformulated as a more general question about the jargon used by some business people, which would be, at least arguably, within the scope of this site.

Comment: Much more context would be needed for any concrete Answer. Failing more context, "points" in finance often means "percentage points" and here, it might well mean "three per cent…" and it might well not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the transcript I added to the question and the season summary on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_Valley_(TV_series)#Season_2) it's pretty safe to assume that they are talking about company equity shares.

The following likely spoilers season two of the show. (I haven't seen it, so I can't judge too precisely.)

> Bream gives Richard the highest offer of all the VC firms: 20% equity at a $100 million valuation. Monica privately visits Richard to urge them to decline the offer, calling it a "runaway valuation that they could never live up to", which would result in diluting Series A investors in future financing rounds. Richard offers Bream the same 20% equity but at a $50 million valuation.

Answer (score 0):

The three points mentioned here are from Season 3 Episode 4 (The Lady) of Silicon Valley where Gilfoyle, Dinesh, and Carla are engaged in a conversation. The usage is

```
Hey, Carla,
How much money do you make here?

Uh, Let's just say
it's a big jump from my old job.

Right, but you probably
got more equity there.

Um, no, actually I get more equity here.

What?

Yeah. Why, what are you guys getting?

Three points each.

Three? That's weird.
I thought you got in at the beginning.
```

It is safe to assume that Gilfoyle and Dinesh mean 3% equity each which seems reasonable for early-stage tech employees both of whom are members of the founding team of Pied Piper.

The equity breakdown was most likely to be:

```
Richard Hendricks - 36%
Russ Hanneman - 10%
Erlich Bachmann - 10%
Peter Gregory - 4.5%
Gilfoyle - 3%
Dinesh - 3%
Jared Dunn - 3%
Monica - 0.5%
Option pool for future hires - 30%*
```